# Spin-only magnetic moment of a coordination complex

Tags: coordination-compounds

While finding the spin-only magnetic moment of a coordination complex, we count the number of unpaired electrons on the central metal atom. What about unpaired electrons on the ligand? Say in the case of $O_2^{-}$ or NO? Won’t they contribute to the magnetic moment?

Comment: Good question, a paramagnetic ligand is an interesting thing. Maybe under some conditions coupling of the magnetic properties of multiple ligands might occur. Could do interesting things

Comment: Free ligand being radical doesn't mean it will be one in complex.